# GAE local php - Mint linux - file storage not working

Tags: php, linux, google-app-engine, file-storage

I'm trying to get a local version of the Google app engine developer console to work with file storage. This works perfect on several windows machines. Yet when i try on a Mint linux system everything works except the file storage.

First of all i had to add following line to the php.ini:

google_app_engine.disable_readonly_filesystem = 1

After that i could upload images, i would see them appear in the developer console under blobstore Viewer. Yet i could not see them in the browser.

When i dug into the logs following messages popped out.

```
ERROR    2016-06-08 20:15:59,459 images_stub.py:438] Could not open image <open file '/tmp/appengine.app app.user/blobs/dev~app-app/n/ncoded_gs_file:cGluZ3ZhbHVlLWJ1Y2tldC1sb2NhbC9zdG9yYWdlL2ltYWdlcy91c2Vycy8xNDY1NDE2OTU3LWltZ2pwZw==', mode 'rb' at 0x7f906e2b2e40> for blob_key 'encoded_gs_file:cGluZ3ZhbHVlLWJ1Y2tldC1sb2NhbC9zdG9yYWdlL2ltYWdlcy91c2Vycy8xNDY1NDE2OTU3LWltZ2pwZw=='
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/images/images_stub.py", line 433, in _OpenBlob
    return Image.open(blob_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1991, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
ApplicationError(4,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 272, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self._handle_request(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 865, in _handle_request
    ret = handler.handle(match, environ, wrapped_start_response)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_handler.py", line 60, in handle
    return self._wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/blob_image.py", line 224, in __call__
    return self.serve_image(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/blob_image.py", line 213, in serve_image
    image, mime_type = self._transform_image(blobkey, resize, crop)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/blob_image.py", line 78, in _transform_image
    image = _get_images_stub()._OpenImageData(image_data)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/images/images_stub.py", line 371, in _OpenImageData
    image = self._OpenBlob(image_data.blob_key())
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/images/images_stub.py", line 441, in _OpenBlob
    images_service_pb.ImagesServiceError.BAD_IMAGE_DATA)
ApplicationError: ApplicationError: 4 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 272, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self._handle_request(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 865, in _handle_request
    ret = handler.handle(match, environ, wrapped_start_response)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_handler.py", line 60, in handle
    return self._wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/blob_image.py", line 224, in __call__
    return self.serve_image(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/blob_image.py", line 213, in serve_image
    image, mime_type = self._transform_image(blobkey, resize, crop)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/blob_image.py", line 78, in _transform_image
    image = _get_images_stub()._OpenImageData(image_data)
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/images/images_stub.py", line 371, in _OpenImageData
    image = self._OpenBlob(image_data.blob_key())
  File "/home/user/Programs/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/images/images_stub.py", line 441, in _OpenBlob
    images_service_pb.ImagesServiceError.BAD_IMAGE_DATA)
```

The message resolves arround bad image data. yet the devserver has no problem reading this.

Are there any actions i could undertake, to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an SELinux issue. Allowing a web server to write to `/home/` isn't normally included in the default SELinux policy.

Check your logs in /var/log/messages, and /var/log/audit/audit.log. You can google for more information on turning SELinux off, or reconfiguring it to allow writing to `/home/`.